# ElasticSearch Query template / function

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using ES query as following. Can I save my query as a template/function on the ES index and calling it from my code?

```
Current Query: "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                        "must": [
                                 {
                                 "terms": {
                                          "bbc.keyword": ["technology"]
                                          }
                                 }
                                 ]
                         }, 
                         { "must": [
                                 {
                                 "terms": {
                                          "cnn.keyword": ["technology"]
                                          }
                                 }
                                 ]
                         }
               }]
```

Looking for:  "should": [
                  {
                    something comes here once (template name or function name does the same thing above)}]

Answer (score 0):

New version of Elasticsearch supports [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) which supports template with mustache language

Answer (score 0):

You can always use index aliases with a filter to store your templates.You can find more information about it here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/indices-aliases.html

Comment: It looks like you cannot pass parameters, it is fixed query, how do you parameterize aliases ?

Comment: I thought you were looking for a constant query. If you have multiple parameters, you can create multiple number of aliases to support each request. The main advantage of using index aliases is that they are scalable and can point to multiple indices.